# Unit Testing xunit The following constructor parameters did not have matching fixture data

Tags: c#, testing, moq, xunit

The following constructor parameters did not have matching fixture data for unit testing using moq and xunit.

Already using dependency injection and mock to test the class.

```
//this is how i register the DI.
services.AddScoped<IWaktuSolatServiceApi, WaktuSolatServiceApi>(); 


 public interface IWaktuSolatServiceApi
 {
    Task<Solat> GetAsyncSet();
 }


// the unit test. 
public class UnitTest1 
{
    Mock<IWaktuSolatServiceApi> waktu;

    public UnitTest1(IWaktuSolatServiceApi waktu)
    {
        this.waktu = new Mock<IWaktuSolatServiceApi>();
    }

    [Fact]
    public async Task ShoudReturn()
    {
        var request = new Solat
        {
            zone = "lala"
        };

        var response = waktu.Setup(x => 
        x.GetAsyncSet()).Returns(Task.FromResult(request));
    }
}
```

But i got this error The following constructor parameters did not have matching fixture data.

Comment: What is the purpose of this test. you are testing the mocking framework.

Comment: This appears to be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Xunit is not using the DI to resolve references.

Remove the constructor argument. Which, in your code sample at least, is unused anyway.

```
// the unit test. 
public class UnitTest1 
{
    Mock<IWaktuSolatServiceApi> waktu;

    /// HERE, remove the parameter
    public UnitTest1()
    {
        this.waktu = new Mock<IWaktuSolatServiceApi>();
    }

    [Fact]
    public async Task ShoudReturn()
    {
        var request = new Solat
        {
            zone = "lala"
        };

        var response = waktu.Setup(x => 
        x.GetAsyncSet()).Returns(Task.FromResult(request));
    }
}
```